# Charging a Li-ion battery using both constant current and constant voltage circuit

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, constant-current

I was developing a wireless charging circuit and have a made the receiver circuit. the circuit is meant to charge a Li-ion battery ([Makita](https://www.makitatools.com/products/details/BL1830B-2)). I have a voltage regulator in the receiver circuit that maintains a voltage of 20 V, and the IC can deliver about 2.5 A, (although I would like it to stay at a constant current of approximately 200 mA). The circuit is not meant to charge the battery fully but rather as a top-up in-between uses. So far the tests that I have conducted are by connected the power supply to the output ends of the full bridge rectifier. This is to test the functionality of the circuit in steps.

Once the circuit was connected to the battery, the battery started to pull high current from the circuit and hence damaging the voltage regulator. I realised that I would need a constant current regulating IC.

My question is, is it possible to have both of the circuits operating at the same time?

I have a LM317 at hand which I want to use, I am still making the circuit to operate with the about receiver circuit. Also there is a diode at the charge tool end to prevent reverse current flowing in the circuit from the battery.

[image]

Comment: `is it possible to have both of the circuits operating at the same time?` That's what the battery charging ICs for. TP4056, for example. maintains constant current output until the battery voltage reaches to some level, then switches to constant voltage with very low output current *(TP4056 is just a well-known example and it can't be used in your application as its maximum operating voltage is 8V yet you need at least 20V. There are lots of different ICs available in the market.)*. You can supply the charging IC with your regulator above to make things easier.

Comment: sure, just set the lm317 as a constant current 200ma supply, fet from your regulated 20v. There's plenty of examples in the TI datasheet.